# How to obtain appropriate equation of this lines?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha:I\to\Bbb R^3$ be a curve with $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha(I)\subset S_{r,c}^2$, where $r>0, c=(c_1,c_2,c_3),$ $S_{r,c}^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:(x-c_1)^2+(y-c_2)^2+(z-c_3)^2=r^2\}$ is a sphere. Prove that $\alpha(I)$ is in a maximum circumference $\iff$ lines generate by the normal vector of $\alpha$ intersect in the center $c$.

I've tried to use that two of those lines are

$\lambda N(s_1)=r\alpha ''(s_1)+\alpha(s_1)$ and $\mu N(s_2)=r\alpha ''(s_2)+\alpha(s_2), \lambda, \mu \in \Bbb R$, where N(s) is the normal vector of $\alpha$ in the point $\alpha(s)$, 
and then made them equal but I don't know how to continue that to obtain that they intersect in the center $c$.

Comment: I haven't yet voted to close, but could you please add to your question: What tools you have available, what you have tried, and where you are unable to make progress? Separately, the article "the" signifies that something is unique; the indefinite article "a" is appropriate when something is not unique, as in "Let $\alpha$ be **a** unit-speed curve in the sphere...." :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've edited to make better my question. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Here's a geometric hint: Let $P$ be the osculating plane at $\alpha(s)$, i.e., the plane through $\alpha(s)$ spanned by $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha''(s)$. Start by showing that the intersection of $P$ with the sphere is the osculating circle of $\alpha$ at $\alpha(s)$.

Comment: Perhaps I might suggest an improvement to the English: You mean to say $\alpha(I)$ is contained in a great circle of the sphere if and only if ... ?

Comment: Yes, English isn't my native language and sometimes it's hard to me. Thank you.